# CRM 2013 Working fine then suddenly 404 error?

Tags: iis-7, dynamics-crm-2013

As the subject says I had a perfectly good CRM 2013 install on 2012 and it was being used. Sometime overnight the site went down. Now I get a 404.0 error. I've disbaled friendly errors...just get a blank page not even a 404. I've modified the web.config debug=true nothing. Fiddler shows nothing...well not exactly. Fiddler shows a 404 as well.

I've removed ssl cert and reapplied. Tried accessing the site http nada?? I looked for any updates that were pushed overnight nothing..(they are disabled but I checked anyway).

If I browse to http it redirects me https as it should. It prompts for my NT credentials as it should. Downloads favicon and decides it has done all it's going to do.

So I am at a real loss as to even getting a clue as to the problem. If someone can help me with some further troubleshooting direction it would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: why the down vote? It you are going to slap me you can at least explain yourself.

Comment: Nothing registers in system logs. The only log I get is IIS telling me 404 0 which I kinda already knew.

Comment: Yes...I am a Dynamics dev a& I don't know the sysadmin stuff as well but I know the sql & dynamics really well and everything looked good there. I found this article and it says "There are several variations of this – but if you aren’t getting *anything* in the logs – start looking at your certificates! More times than not – it is the SSL certificate and you aren’t even getting to ADFS which is why there aren’t any error messages to work with. " so I am heading down that path at the moment. I'll post back if I get anywhere.

Comment: Fyi link to article is: http://blogs.technet.com/b/adfs/archive/2007/07/23/adfs-certificates-ssl-token-signing-and-client-authentication-certs.aspx

Comment: Keep adding details to your question and make sure you post your solution as an answer if you find out what caused this issue. I come back and add anything that could be useful.